# Is there an application like VeraCrypt which supports TOTP or other changable parameter?

Tags: linux, windows, security, veracrypt

I am looking for a multi-platform application - Windows + Linux that will create a container to keep files there with some predefined password + TOTP or any other changeable parameter that would protect the container if a password leaks.